# Список из массивов

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть структура, описывающая список, элементом которого является целое число и процедура по добавлению элемента в список:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
void Add(int x){
    size++;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->data = x;

    if (head != NULL){
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else{
        head = tail = temp;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы элементом списка был массив, размер которого вводит пользователь?

Comment: статический или динамический?

Comment: два поля: размер массива и указатель на массив. При добавлении - создаете массив требуемого размера, при удалении - уничтожаете. Размер запрашиваете у пользователя, используете при создании массива, и сохраняете рядом с массивом

Comment: `std::list<std::vector<int>>` и привет преподу. А по сути, если у вас есть поле типа `int`, которое хранит данные, то очевидно, что на его месте должен быть просто другой тип - ваш этот *"массив, размер которого вводит пользователь"*. Вот и создайте этот тип для начала.